# How to Add a Paragraph Object to a Document

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I have recently been using docx for word document processing and I was messing around with it and I could not find a way to add a paragraph object to a document. You can call the add_parragraph method from the document instance, but that does not accept paragraph objects, just text and styles.

I want to do this (psuedo-code)

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document(document)
doc1 = docx.Document()

firstp = doc.parragraphs[0]

doc1.add_parragraph(firstp)

doc1.save("test")
```

Unfortunately, docx does not support this. Is there an alternative for python?

Comment: Short answer is "no". There is no API support for adding a paragraph object to a document. What are you trying to achieve that this seems like a good approach for?

Comment: I would like to randomize a test and I just thought it would be simple if you randomize the order of the paragraphs and then add them as objects so I do not have to extract the style and text. Also I can't think of any way to transfer pictures as well.

Comment: This could be accomplished by digging into the underlying XML and copying XML elements and inserting them where desired, but that's a pretty hefty learning curve.